# SlimDX Directx 9 problem

Tags: c#, .net, directx, slimdx

I am getting the Following problem when i try to initialize the directx

> SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D9NotFoundException
>   was unhandled   Message="Direct3D 9
>   was not found. Reinstalling DirectX
>   may fix the problem

code:

```
Direct3DEx m_d3dEx = new Direct3DEx();
```

I checked the version of Directx installed on my PC via dxdiag utility it shows that i have Directx 9c installed.

what is the cause of the problem.

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My "guess" is that you aren't running Vista.  Direct3DEx can only be created on a Vista machine.

Edit:

Change your code to

```
Direct3D m_d3d = new Direct3D();
```

And that "should" fix you.

Comment: can u please guide me for windows xp

Answer (score 0):

When was the last time you installed DirectX, and what version? Also, what version of SlimDX are you using? I'm thinking that the version of DirectX you have installed is earlier than the version of SlimDX you have, which is why they dont work well with each other. I suggest you install the latest DirectX SDK, as well as the latest SlimDX.

Comment: no it did not work i tried reinstalling the SlimDX and DirectxSDK